# How to take value from array of inputs

Tags: jquery

I have form with inputs

```
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
```

How I can receive data from 3rd input, for example?

This construction doesn't work

```
$('input[name="name[2]"]').val();
```

Comment: `$('input:text:nth-child(3)').val();`

Comment: `$('input:text:eq(2)').val();`

Comment: @2oppin i doubt it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:eq()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method

```js
alert($('input:text:eq(2)').val());
alert($('input:text').eq(2).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
<input type="text" name="name[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one who writes the inputs, the best practice here is to use ids

```
<input id="input1" type="text" name="name[]">
<input id="input2" type="text" name="name[]">
<input id="input3" type="text" name="name[]">
<input id="input4" type="text" name="name[]">
<input id="input5" type="text" name="name[]">
```

To recover de data of the input:

```
var text = $('#input3').val();
```